# How to bind data to template driven form from a list / table using Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

> Here is My code for update data.

**table.Component.html**

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            Action
          </button>
          <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <a class="mat-menu-item" type="button" (click)="showForEdit(data)">Edit</a>
            <a class="mat-menu-item" type="button" href="#">Details</a>
            <a class="mat-menu-item" type="button" href="#">Delete</a>
          </mat-menu>
        </td>
</ng-container>
```

**table.component.ts**

```
 showForEdit(obj: any) {
    debugger;
    this.roleService.GetRoleById(obj.id)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.objRoleModel = response;
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/roles/Create");
          console.log(response);

        },
        error => {
          console.log(' err ' + error);
        }
      );
  }
```

My requirement is that i want to fetch data from table in create form for update. in short when i click on edit button then i want to see data filled in create form. Data will be created and updated using same form.

> Here is my code for Create and Update.

**form.component.html**

```
      <form #Roleadd='ngForm' class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="CreateRole(Roleadd)">
        <h4>Role Name</h4>
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
          <input matInput placeholder="Enter Role" name="roleName" roleName required [(ngModel)]="objRoleModel.RoleName"
            #roleName="ngModel">
        </mat-form-field>
        <section class="section">
          <mat-checkbox name="isActive" [(ngModel)]="objRoleModel.IsActive" #isActive ="ngModel">Is Active</mat-checkbox>
        </section>
        <mat-card-actions>

            <button mat-flat-button type="submit" color="primary">Create New</button>
            <button mat-flat-button type="button" color="primary" (click)="backtolist()">Back to List</button>

        </mat-card-actions>
      </form>
```

**form.component.ts**

```
  CreateRole(regForm: NgForm) {

    if (regForm.value.Id == null) {

      this.objRoleModel.RoleName = regForm.value.roleName;
      this.objRoleModel.IsActive = regForm.value.isActive;

      this.roleService.CreateRole(this.objRoleModel).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(this.objRoleModel);
        alert("Role Added Successfully !!");
      })
    }
    else {

      this.roleService.updateRole(this.objRoleModel).subscribe(res => {
        alert("Role Updated Successfully !!");
      });
    }

  }
```

> Here is my service class

**Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { RoleModel } from "../models/role.model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoleService {

  objRoleModel: RoleModel;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    this.objRoleModel = new RoleModel();
  }




  GetRoleById(Id): Observable<any> {
    debugger;
    return this.http.get("https://localhost:44336/api/Roles/" + Id)
      .pipe(
        map((response: Response) => {
          return response;
        }),
        catchError((error: Response) => {
          return throwError(console.log(error));
        })
      );
  }

  CreateRole(objRoleModel: RoleModel) {
    debugger;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
    var body = {
      Id: objRoleModel.Id,
      RoleName: objRoleModel.RoleName,
      IsActive: objRoleModel.IsActive
    }
    return this.http.post<RoleModel>("https://localhost:44336/api/Roles", body, { headers });

  }

  updateRole(objRoleModel: RoleModel) {
    debugger;
    const params = new HttpParams().set("Id", objRoleModel.Id.toString());
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('content-type', 'application/json');
    var body = {
      Id: objRoleModel.Id,
      RoleName: objRoleModel.RoleName,
      IsActive: objRoleModel.IsActive
    }
    return this.http.put<RoleModel>("https://localhost:44336/api/Roles?" + objRoleModel.Id, body, { headers, params })
  }
}
```

Comment: do you want to share data between one component to another component?

Comment: Yes, Create form and table both are different  component , i want to update data (which are shown in table) using Create form component.

Comment: share us the full code, or create a stackblitz if you can.

Comment: @BearNithi i have updated my post and shared full code. please check

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can solve your problem by creating a service.  and share data between components with the use of service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a service to share data between your components. Here, i have shared you a service, which is used to set values and get values in a Singleton Object. Inject this service in your module's provider and declare it in your **table.component.ts** and **form.component.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

/**
 * A singleton service to store data throughout the application lifecycle.
 *
 */
@Injectable()
export class SessionService {

  private sessionLevel: any = {};  

  setSessionVar(key: string, value: any): void {
    this.sessionLevel[key] = value;
  }

  getSessionVar(key: string): any {
    return this.sessionLevel[key];
  }
};
```

In your table.component.ts, on edit button click you should set the value

```
 showForEdit(obj: any) {
    this.roleService.GetRoleById(obj.id)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.objRoleModel = response;
          this.sessionService.setSessionVar('SELECTED_ITEM',response);
          this.router.navigateByUrl("/roles/Create");
          console.log(response);

        },
        error => {
          console.log(' err ' + error);
        }
      );
  }
```

In your **form.component.ts**, on **ngOnInit** you should get the value

```
public objRoleModel: any = {};
ngOnInit() {
   if(this.sessionService.getSessionVar('SELECTED_ITEM')) {
     const data = this.sessionService.getSessionVar('SELECTED_ITEM');
     this.objRoleModel.RoleName = data.roleName;
     this.objRoleModel.IsActive = data.isActive;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply,
Can you Explain me further
like  what can i pass in place of "SELECTED_ITEM".

Comment: "SELECTED_ITEM" is just a key (property) name we want to set in our singleton object, you can set whatever name you want.

Comment: No, problem is still same, data is not shown in form when i click on edit.

Comment: have you created a service which i have showed in the answer

Comment: yes, i have created a service and declared in provider array of app.module.ts

Comment: have you declared in your `constructor(private sessionService: SessionService)` in both `table.component.ts` and `form.component.ts`

Comment: then, it will work, debug the code in setSessionVar and getSessionVar. share me what it results. whether the response has value or not etc.

Comment: **Value** parameter of function shows the data like id, name etc. and in console shows the json  `{id: 7, roleName: "Employees", isActive: true, menuPermission: Array(0), roleUser: Array(0)}`

Comment: your ngModel name and the server response property names are different, i have updated the answer. bind individual value to ngModel in ngOnInit

Comment: Whooo Finally Got it Solved.
Thanks for Your Time And Help.
Again Thank You Very very much.

Comment: Most welcome, change your question as i suggested so that people who face the same issue will get the solution easily.